# Tweepy Status.created_at time is not consistent with the actual time the timeline

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, python-datetime

I have a 'tweet' object collected using `tweepy` in Python. The object has attribute `created_at` which should give the posting time of the tweet.

Here is the case. Let `x` be the tweet object. I have result

`x.full_text`

`'18 suspects arrested for involvement in public gaming activities, including mahjong....'`

and

`x.created_at`

`datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 22, 10, 16, 40)`

which means that the tweet was created on 22 June 2018 at 10:16 AM. But, **the time in the timeline shows that it is posted at around 16-17 PM on the same date.**

May I get clarification on this?

The tweet is from The Strait Times Twitter account.

Comment: Strong hunch that this is related with time zones.

Comment: @BcK I am in Jakarta, and The Strait Times is a Singapore news media. So the time difference is not that big.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date and time "created_at" is given via the API is UTC. See the reference at *[Tweet Object](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object)*.

> Attribute:createad_at, type:String, description: UTC time when this Tweet was created

When you are logged into the official web site, tweets date are converted to the time zone you have set into your profile settings.

Comment: So every `datetime` object from `tweepy` will be in UTC? regardless of my profile settings or any other external settings.

Comment: yes, look at the created_at attribute at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object